# Cypress: How to make button element clicked multiple time in a row not waiting?

Tags: javascript, testing, next.js, cypress

Im trying to write some tests codes on my sign in page(Next, NextAuth) and I am stuck with this situation.

On my sign in page, there is a button that submits the user info to the backend, handling the API request.

I made the button to be locked by adding 'pointer-events: none' css properties while it is requesting API for users not sending multiple sign in requests in a row.

I tried to test the scenario where the button is locked expectedly when user clicks the button again while it is sending API request with Cypress.

But I cannot recreate this behavior because of the reason that Cypress always waits the API request finishing.

I tried to set options on the cy.click() action with the {multiple: true, force: true} but it doesn't seem to work as I expect.

Is there any ways to test this specific action?

Should I write the test with different approaches?

[Tests codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWpi9.png)
[Tests result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovQxg.png)

Appriciated.

Read related Cypress docs, Github issues,  Stackoverflow questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress doesn't necessarily wait for the HTTP call to finish.

If you want to wait for a call, there is a special mechanism with `cy.intercept` and `cy.wait`.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.

In your case, you can intercept the call and add a delay.

```
cy.intercept({
    url: '/login',
    times: 1
  }, (req) => {
    req.reply( (res) => {
      res.delay = 5000
    })
  })
```

Comment: thank you in advance. I read about the link you attached and I understand a bit of the concept of the intercept. So I tried to add your codes to the test but it seems not working unfortunately. Could you help this situation? I will add some images and codes that explains my situation.

Comment: Could you try `/api/auth/**` ?

Comment: And remove `times:1`

Comment: It worked as I wanted! Thank you very much! But could you explain why those two lines affected the code to work or not please?

Comment: For `/api/auth/**`, `**` means **every** things after. In your case, for example the CallBack wouldn't be considered with just `*`. About `times:1`, that means that it will match 1 call and the next will not be considered. In our case, we wanted to consider all the auth calls.

Comment: Understood very well. Appreciate all of your helps!